# show image on client before upload on server in gwt

Tags: gwt, image-uploading

I would like to show an image and its dimensions on the client before uploading it to the server. Whenever I try to create an `Image` widget of gwt ext, it doesn't accept a local file (on the file system). It only accepts http requests. I also tried `String img = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "image_name"` and the replace function but with same result. Finally I moved to `ImagePreloader` but its also needs a URL.

```
ImagePreloader.load("URL of image", new ImageLoadHandler()
{
    public void imageLoaded(ImageLoadEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.isLoadFailed())
            Window.alert("Image " + event.getImageUrl() + "failed to load.");
        else
            Window.alert("Image dimensions: " + event.getDimensions().getWidth() + " x " + event.getDimensions().getHeight());
    }
});
```

Can someone suggest a solution that doesn't include uploading the image first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the sample JS code below:

```
function readURL(input) {

if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}

 $("#imgInp").change(function(){
   readURL(this);
});
```

and the associated HTML:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

Comment: -1 You just copied [another SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/1449199) that isn't yours and posted it here. And you didn't even include the jsfiddle that shows it works.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this related question and answer:

[Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

You can include it using JSNI. I'm now aware of a solution within GWT.

---

Just found [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) which claims to be able to preview images before uploading them.

Comment: Thanks for reply i used gwtupload but its servlet creation a local directory structure than sending the url to client its working after uploading the file ...

Comment: i am new in jsni. how its use i dont know i used it on simple java script and html but its not working . please help ...

Comment: ya i see it but in the following html code how the function calling and how can i call this function using GWt Ext file upload  <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>