# GWT/Javascript: Get Url Of User-Selected Local File

Tags: javascript, gwt

In a program I'm writing, I'd like to have the user select an image on the local machine via a file-selection dialog and then be able to insert the path of that image as the `src` attribute of an `img` tag.

```
<img src="file:/path/to/selected/image.png">
```

I'm using GWT right now and tried the `FileUpload` class but the `getFilename()` method doesn't return a real path under most browsers -- Windows Chrome returns it as `C:\fakepath\image.png`.

*Is there a way, either under GWT or native Javascript, that will get the real path of a locally selected file?*

Comment: Why do you need the real path of a locally selected file?

Comment: Uhhh...  So I can insert it as the `src` attribute of an `img` tag.  Is there something else you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the link provided by Braj...  Here's how I did it:

```
private String imageDataUrl;

static private native void observeFileSelection(MainActivity main, Element uploader, Element error) /*-{
    function handleFileSelect(selevt) {
        error.innerHTML = "";

        var file = selevt.target.files[0];
        if (file.size > 1 * 1024 * 1024) {
            error.innerHTML = "Error: Image must be less that 1MiB in size.";
            return;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (loadevt) {
            main.@com.example.app.MainActivity::setSelectedImageDataUrl(Ljava/lang/String;)(loadevt.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    uploader.addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
}-*/;

public void setSelectedImageDataUrl(String dataurl) {
    imageDataUrl = dataurl;
}

private void handleOverlayButton() {
    final DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();

    final HTMLPanel htmlpanel = new HTMLPanel(
            S.mainOverlayChooseText() + "<hr><div id='fileupload'></div><div id='fileerror' style='color:red'></div><hr>");
    dialog.setHTML("<b>" + S.mainOverlayChooseTitle() + "</b>");
    dialog.add(htmlpanel);
    dialog.setAnimationEnabled(true);
    dialog.setGlassEnabled(true);
    dialog.addStyleName("info-dialog");

    final FileUpload file = new FileUpload();
    file.setName("imgfile");
    htmlpanel.add(file, "fileupload");
    final SimplePanel error = new SimplePanel();
    htmlpanel.add(error, "fileerror");

    final Button ok = new Button(S.buttonOk());
    ok.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            dialog.hide();
            dialog.clear();
            setOverlayImage(imageDataUrl);
            imageDataUrl = null;
        }
    });
    htmlpanel.add(ok);

    final Button cancel = new Button(S.buttonCancel());
    cancel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            dialog.hide();
            dialog.clear();
            imageDataUrl = null;
        }
    });
    htmlpanel.add(cancel);

    dialog.center();
    dialog.show();
    observeFileSelection(this, file.getElement(), error.getElement());
}

private void setOverlayImage(String dataurl) {
    // just for testing
    final AbsolutePanel overlay = new AbsolutePanel();
    final Image image = new Image(dataurl);
    overlay.add(image);
    RootPanel.get().add(overlay);
}
```

Hope that helps if others are trying to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are interested in showing the image on client before upload on server in GWT.

Please have a look at below post:

- [show image on client before upload on server in gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861966/show-image-on-client-before-upload-on-server-in-gwt)

Comment: I don't actually want to upload the image.  I want to be able to display it as an overlay, make some simple adjustments on it (css) and output some numbers once it looks the way the user wants.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get the real path of a locally selected file from a browser with javascript. It' a question of security. With HTML5 you could get the image itself and achieve what you want to achieve. THere's  a nice lib for this: [lib-gwt-file.jar](http://www.vectomatic.org/libs/lib-gwt-file)

Comment: Why is it insecure to know the pathname of a file the user selected?

Comment: Javascript code would have access to the filesystem of the user, As far as i know no browser allows that

Comment: However you can read the file with HTML5, put it in a Canvas and process it as you like.

Comment: I suppose..  It could insert the filename as a `src` tag to a `script` element.  But this is a filename selected by the user through a dialog which makes it an explicit user action.  But it is what it is, I guess.

Comment: I looked at that library, but it ended up being easier just to write a few lines of "native" Javascript instead.